# How to use values stored in secrets.yml in initialization files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

```
Rails 4.2.1
Ruby 2.1.5
```

In initializers/devise.rb, I have:

```
config.omniauth :facebook, facebook_app_id, facebook_app_secret
```

In config/secrets.yml, I have:

```
development:
  secret_key_base: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  facebook_app_id: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  facebook_app_secret: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

When I try running rake db:migrate, I get the following error message:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `facebook_app_id' for main:Object
```

My understanding is that I can define these values in secrets.yml and use them in devise.rb. Is this correct? If so, why am I getting this error message.

I also tried, in devise.rb:

```
config.omniauth :facebook, Rails.application.facebook_app_id, Rails.application.facebook_app_secret
```

But I still got the same error message:
    rake aborted!
    NoMethodError: undefined method `facebook_app_id' for #

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can access these values by

`Rails.application.secrets.facebook_app_id`

`Rails.application.secrets.facebook_app_secret`

Comment: I tried it, but it did not work. Please see the edit to my question.

Comment: sorry i missed `.secrets`